# What is the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}_n(x)|x]-f^*(x)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a standard ERM problem based on quadratic loss where we solve
$$
\hat{f}_n\in \arg min_{f\in \mathcal{F}} R_{tr}(f)
$$
where $R_{tr}(f)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-f(X_i))^2$, $\{(X_i, Y_i): i=1,\dots, n\}$ is the training dataset, and $$\mathcal{F}:=\{f_\theta: f_\theta(x)=\sum_{i=0}^9 \theta_i x^i , \theta_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ the class of polynomials of degree at most $9$. Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

Assume that $f^*(x)=\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]=2x+1$. Let $X\sim Unif(-1, 1)$ and $Var[Y|X]=5$.

Question: can we get the conditional bias of the estimator at a generic $x$, $$\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}_n(x)|x]-f^*(x)$$?

Here we take conditional bias conditioned on the training data $\{X_i\}$.